# The distance between $5$ wave troughs is $64$ cm. Determine the wavelenght.

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

> The distance between $5$ wave troughs is $64$ cm. Determine the
>   wavelenght.

I thought that

$$5 \lambda = 64$$
$$\lambda = 12.8$$

However, the correct answer seems $16$, why?

Regards!

Comment: Can anyone take a look? This is not possible really. $5$ wave troughs means there are $5$ wave.

Comment: Isn't there a physicist who can take a look at this question?

Comment: Is this an off-by-oneeffect? $\lambda=16$ means there are five wave-throughs at $0,16,32,48,64$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, right. I've seen my fault.

Comment: This is a maths forum though, not a physics one. (regarding to your "isn't there a physicist who can take a look at this question")

Comment: The problem is poorly expressed, though, and you can’t be blamed for missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only $4$ wavelengths. The distance between TWO wave troughs is one wavelength. If you plot several periods, it is the distance between $5$ and $1$, $5-1=4$